# Connecting JBoss 5.1 MDBs to Websphere MQ queues

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I'm trying to upgrade a system running jboss3.x to jboss5.1.
The system uses MDB's listening on queues in WebSphere MQ, so the 'message-driven' is connected to a Container/'invoker-proxy-binding' via 'configuration-name' - the standard way to connect to a remote queue - I guess.

The problem with JBoss 5.1 is that `jboss_5_1.xsd` does not have the `configuration-name` and the `invoker-proxy-binding`. All examples  on connecting JBoss 5.1 MDB's connecting to remote queues, I found so far, is not using the `jboss_5_1.xsd`, but in stead uses `jboss_5_0.dtd`.

What do I miss by using `jboss_5_0.dtd`, and how is it supposed to be configured in 5.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I know it is a bit old question, but anyway: I have it working on 5.1 using an activation config defined in ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml

```
<domain name="zzz.ejb.mdb.MessageReceiver" extends="Message Driven Bean" inheritBindings="true">
     <!-- annotation must be documented on one line without CR/LF -->
     <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs)">
                        @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs ({ @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messagingType", propertyValue="javax.jms.MessageListener"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "zzz/jms/LocalQueue"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "ZZZ.QMGR"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "172.21.100.10"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1415"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"), @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxPoolDepth", propertyValue = "1")})
    </annotation>
</domain>
```

Note that the annotations are in a single line.

In addition, I have an mbean defined for the queue (like this):

```
        <mbean code="org.jboss.resource.deployment.AdminObject" name="jboss.jca:service=WASDestination,name=zzz/jms/LocalQueue">
            <attribute name="JNDIName">zzz/jms/LocalQueue</attribute>
            <depends optional-attribute-name="RARName">jboss.jca:service=RARDeployment,name='wmq.jmsra.rar'</depends>
            <attribute name="Type">javax.jms.Queue</attribute>
            <attribute name="Properties">
                    baseQueueManagerName=ZZZ.QMGR
                    baseQueueName=ZZZ.QUEUE
            </attribute>
    </mbean>
```

I hope this helps